# Font Awesome 5 Icons not working on Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I was trying to add the github (`class="fas fa-github"`) icon on a bootstrap dark button, but the button icon and text doesn't appear (the console shows nothing)

Code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-4">Henrique Borges</h1>
    <p class="lead">Programador experiente e Web Designer.</p>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
    <p class="lead">
    <a class="fas fa-github btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Github</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I´ve already included both the BS and FA libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/fontawesome-all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is the Font Awesome CSS added?

Comment: Do i really need to include Font Awesome CSS?

Comment: Well where do you think the CSS classes come from, like `fas` and `fas-github`?

Comment: Font awesome 5 used to work with including only the fontawesome-all.min.js

Comment: Tried adding the css, but nothing happened, just the page load time has doubled :/

Comment: I already solved it! i was using the `class="fab fa-github"` on the `<a>` tag (when it must be used on `<i>` tags

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try the snippet. Changed the `fas fa-github` to `fab fa-github`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">



<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">Henrique Borges</h1>
  <p class="lead">Programador experiente e Web Designer.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
  <p class="lead">
    <i class="fab fa-github btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="#" role="button"> Github</i>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but can you explain why? `fas` should work, too, no?

Comment: @ThomasJensen, As I know there are 4 icon types in font awesome, 1. fab - brands, fas or fa - solid, far - regular, fal - light. So in their documentation for a icon like github, they have provided the prefix as "fab" https://fontawesome.com/icons/github?style=brands .

Answer (score 9):

I have run into this problem before, particularly with the `fas` class. For me it has always been manually upgrading my font awesome style sheet tag in my head.

For whatever reason, dependency managers like yarn don't always have the very latest version of font awesome.

> https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css

```
<!-- FontAwesome -->
  <link 
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 1):

`.fas` class will only work with `font-weight: 900`. make sure you have `font-weight: 900`.

you are using multiple classes `fas fa-github btn btn-dark btn-lg` if any of these does not have `font-weight: 900` font will not show up.

try this

```
.btn {
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: Font Awesome `fas` class already sets the `font-weight: 900` by default, no need to hardcode it on another class, and also, using `!important` is a bad practice

Comment: but if you are using fas with some other class like .btn it will over write font-weight: 900 and icon will not display. this is the problem he is facing.  and to over write this rule you need to add !important...

Comment: @henriquehbr as with many things, "!important" is a tool that needs to be used correctly, not blanketed as a bad practice.